# How to use same stored procedure for different tables and avoid using dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have quite a few tables which contain some common columns (same name and datatype). On these columns I need to perform the same operations and I would like to do that via a stored procedure. However the only way I can make it work at the moment is using dynamic sql, which I'd rather avoid.

Is there any way to use a stored procedure for different tables (where the table name is handed over as parameter) without using dynamic sql?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid dynamic SQL?

Comment: @JonSeigel Because I find it much more difficult to maintain than "normal" sql: Intellisense won't work etc. Basically I don't want to use dynamic SQL as long as there is another approach that's still ok. Good question though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other thing you could do is create a view that unions the like tables together, and include a defined column with the table name, then just do a select against that view with the tablename in the where clause.

```
CREATE VIEW tablesviews AS
SELECT columns, 'TABLE1' as tablename
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT columns, 'TABLE2' as tablename
FROM Table2
...


SELECT {some columns}
FROM  tableviews
WHERE Tablename=@table and [other where clauses]
```

Answer (score 3):

one way i could think of is below..

```
create proc dynamictable   
(     
@name varchar(100)    
)     
as     
begin    
if @name ='tablename1'    
begin    
select columns from tablename1    
end     
if@name='tablename2'    
begin   
select columns from tablename2    
end   
end
```

Comment: It is often seen for event distribution, journals, logs, that the name of a table is selected from another control table, allowing rotation.